# using set() methode to change a class object properties that are in the constructor class

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a Car class that has four constructors. I want change the `Car` constructor property using `set()` methods.

```
class Car(var color: String) {
    // Getter returns the current color
    get() = field
    
    // Setter assigns the new color to the field
    set(value) {
        field = value
    }
}

fun main() {
    val myCar = Car("Red") // Create a car with an initial color

    println("Current color: ${myCar.color}") // Print the current color

    myCar.color = "Blue" // Change the color using the setter

    println("New color: ${myCar.color}") // Print the new color
}
```

I expected to be able to change the color (property) of the car (class) from the object of the class. I tried to define a property in the class and all of the sudden everything works.

Why is that a defined property in the class constructor is in the same scope of the whole class, it should have worked.

Comment: Why do you need a custom setter at all? Just declare `var color: String` as a constructor property and done.

Comment: "I appreciate your input, and I understand that my approach might not have been the most conventional one. However, I was genuinely curious about why I couldn't change the value using the set() method. Thank you for shedding light on this aspect

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a property color in the primary constructor of the Car class, which means it's a constructor parameter that automatically becomes a property of the class. In Kotlin, properties declared in the primary constructor are automatically part of the class, and you can use them just like any other class property without needing to define a separate property explicitly.

Here's your modified code without explicitly defining color as a property:

```
class Car(var color: String) {
    // Getter returns the current color
    get() = field

    // Setter assigns the new color to the field
    set(value) {
        field = value
    }
}

fun main() {
    val myCar = Car("Red") // Create a car with an initial color

    println("Current color: ${myCar.color}") // Print the current color

    myCar.color = "Blue" // Change the color using the setter

    println("New color: ${myCar.color}") // Print the new color
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just save your primary constructor color property into another variable in your **Car** class

```
fun main() {
    var myCar = Car("Red") // Create a car with an initial color
    println("Current color: ${myCar.color}") // Print the current color
    myCar.color = "Blue" // Change the color using the setter
    println("New color: ${myCar.color}") // Print the new color
}

class Car(var color: String){

    var changeColor = color
    // Getter returns the current color
    get() = field
    // Setter assigns the new color to the field
    set(value) {
        field = value
    }

}
```

Comment: you'r right i thought about that but why add an extra line of code defining a propertie that's already been defined in the class constructor and i'm  just curious about why I couldn't change the value using the set() method.

Comment: @zahraoui 
In Kotlin, you can't access the values of properties defined in a class constructor using the set() function because properties defined in a class constructor are not accessible like regular properties defined in the class body.

Comment: @zahraoui If you want to make color value mutable and accessible using the set() method, you should define it as a property in the class body and not as a constructor parameter:

Comment: thanx i get it now, I really appreciate you taking the time to explain things so clearly and concisely.